# Reloading Webpage every x Seconds (Swift)

Tags: html, swift, webview, timer, refresh

I have an application that displays a webpage, I would like to reload the webpage every 30 seconds. Below is the current code that I have put together. I am still a novice in swift coding and might be using a few depreciated syntax:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          
        
        func CGRectMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect
        {
            return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        }
        let webViewClass : AnyObject.Type = NSClassFromString("UIWebView")!
        let webViewObject : NSObject.Type = webViewClass as! NSObject.Type
        let webview: AnyObject = webViewObject.init()
        let url = NSURL(string: "URL")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        let uiview = webview as! UIView
        uiview.frame = CGRectMake(-79, -60, 2080, 1200)
        view.addSubview(uiview)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
    }
    
    @objc func update() 
    {
         webView.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What issue are you having? Show your attempt to setup and use a timer. Please update your question with more specific details. And why are you creating a UIWebView in such a strange way? And more importantly, why aren't you using a WKWebView? UIWebView was deprecated many years ago. Also, why are you using so many `NS` classes? Use `URL`, not `NSURL`. Use `URLRequest`, not `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: @HangarRash, have just modified the code with the current working cord that im getting the error with. I do know the issue is because it is unable to see the web view in the scope, I just don't know how to restructure it to make it work.

Comment: Make `webView` an instance property of the class instead of a local variable inside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: what is the error you get?